# Dynamic Bool Query for NEST (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic Bool Query. Example...

```
        QueryContainer addressQuery = null;
        QueryContainer typeQuery = null;

        BoolQueryDescriptor <Facility> boolQuery = new BoolQueryDescriptor<Facility>();
        QueryContainerDescriptor<Facility> sh = new QueryContainerDescriptor<Facility>();
        SearchDescriptor<Facility> mainSh = new SearchDescriptor<Facility>();
        if (search.searchTerm != null)
        {
            addressQuery = sh.Term(f => f.Address, search.searchTerm) ||
                                            sh.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Address).Query(search.searchTerm) ) ||
                                            sh.Term(f => f.ZipCode, search.searchTerm) ||
                                            sh.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.State).Query(search.searchTerm));
            boolQuery = boolQuery.Should(b => addressQuery);
        }
        if (search.type != null) {
            typeQuery = sh.Term(f => f.Types.First(), search.type);
            boolQuery = boolQuery.Must(b => typeQuery && addressQuery);
        }

        if (boolQuery != null)
        {
           mainSh = mainSh.Query(q => q.Bool(b => boolQuery));
           request = await this._elasticClient.SearchAsync<Facility>(s => mainSh.Size(search.size));
        }
```

This query is turning into a OR between `AddressQuery` and `TypeQuery` however, I'd like to achieve an **And** condition between both query. Effectively making the query dynamic. Is this possible? Example: dynamic `addressQuery && typeQuery`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fire it out..you can `&&` or `||` query containers...sorter like:

```
 queryContainer1=queryContainer1 && queryContainer2
```

Then `.bool(b => b(queryContainer1))`.